# float:left not working properly

Tags: html, css

There is a div container #filters that holds all DOM components. Each DOM components is assigned with class 'form-field-in-a-row'. Here is the css definition:

```
div#filters { border: solid 0px #ccc; }
div#filters .dijitTextBox { width: 150px; }
div#filters input.submit { width: 60px; float: left;  margin-top: 25px; margin-right: 3px;}
div#filters input.reset { width: 60px; float: left;  margin-top: 25px; margin-left: 3px;}
.form-field-in-a-row { margin: 10px 0px; min-height: 22px; width: 200px; float: left;}
```

Now I can see each DOM object does deploy from left to right but still on a stack, like this:

[image]

Then how can I actually put everything in a row without the height difference?

Comment: Can you post a complete code example please, including your HTML?

Comment: Post your HTML since the CSS by itself does not specify the problem to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`display:inline-block;` should be applied to your `divs`. The `inline` makes them go on the same line and the `block` lets you assign a `width + height` to them through CSS.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to put a `display:inline;` on them they should move inline with one another.